How to install Owl2UML plugin in Protege 5.6.4?
Normal google search shows me a wikilink (http://apps.lumii.lv/owl2uml/) to download jar for owl2uml plugin but thats for protege4 and also downloaded insecurely.
Kindly help in redirecting me to authentic link for downloading and installing Owl2UML plugin in Protege 5.6.4 and also how to activate or enable to use it?

Wiki page of the latest version of the plugin (0.0.3).
There is a download link on the wiki page.
I suspect that the link is not https because the latest version of the plugin was released 15 years ago (then it was normal to use http, apparently the storage server has not been modernized since then).
As stated on the wiki page:

Compatible Protege Version:  Protege-OWL 4.0

Based on this statement, I assume that the plugin OWL2UML 0.0.3 does not work with the Protege 5.6.4.
